# docker-sync not working after update to macOS Ventura

Tags: docker, macos

I updated to new macOS Ventura and docker-sync stoped working. When I run `docker-sync sync` it is synchronized but `docker-sync start` doesn't sync it automatically but before update it worked just fine.

I tried update Docker, docker-sync, unison but nothing helped.

Can you help me please?

Best regards

Comment: Having the same issue here -- please update if you've found a solution

Comment: looks like there's a github issue for this: https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/issues/826

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @DanielRead!

I changed `sync_strategy:` to `'native_osx'` in my `docker-sync.yml` and it seems that it works.

Thank you!